# Middleware auth redirecting to home

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I created a services provider and in the boot method I put the following code

```
Route::prefix($this->prefix)
            ->middleware('auth')
            ->group(app_path($this->module_path. '/Routes/route.php'));
```

When I try to access the routes found in the route file defined in the above file, I am redirected to /home.
The same does not happen when I remove the auth middleware declaration or if I define the route in laravel's default route file. I also got success when I set the routes file in the RouteServiceProvider.
It looks like the redirection only happens when it's defined in another service provider.

1 - Add the code below in a new Service Provider.

```
Route::prefix($this->prefix)
            ->middleware('auth')
            ->group(app_path($this->module_path. '/Routes/route.php'));
```

2 - Register the service provider in the app.php file.
3 - Create the routes in the file defined in the service provider in step 1.
4 - Check that it does not redirect to /home.

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't solve it, but I found the problem.
I tried putting the ['auth','web'] middleware, but it redirected me forever to the login screen and then home.

But when you put ['web','auth'] it works correctly.